# spark-submit in local mode - configuration

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I am doing a `spark-submit` using `--master local` on my laptop (spark 1.6.1) to load data into hive tables. Laptop has 8 GB RAM and 4 cores. I have not set any properties manually - just using defaults.

When I load 50k records, the jobs finishes successfully. But when I try and load 200k records, I get a "GC Overhead Limit Exceeded" error.

In --master local mode, are there properties for job memory or heap memory that could be set manually?

Answer (score 7):

Try to increase --driver-memory, --executor-memory,   default value is 1g for both.

command should be like this:

```
spark-submit --master local --driver-memory 2g --executor-memory  2g  --class classpath jarfile
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Arvind. Will try that. But in my case its my laptop - just one machine. The driver is the executor. In such a case, I should be trying different values of --driver-memory! - Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: @xplorerdev Even it is one machine, one machine act as driver and executor as well.  If I see program I can understand you are getting error  "GC Overhead Limit Exceeded" at driver level or executor level. At this moment I'm not sure where exactly you are getting error.That is the reason I have given two options.  you can try --driver-memory first and if  it is not solved try  --executor-memory.

Comment: how do we install the spark-submit script?